# Request reviewer's name in Autodesk BIM 360 approval workflow

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

In Autodesk BIM 360 one can set up approval workflows for documents: One Step Approval, Two Step Approval, etc.

My problem is that I cannot find an API to request data about the approvals. For example, I would like to know which document was approved by whom.

For an one step approval workflow I found a solution. There is a setting that an approved file is automatically copied to a new folder. When I call `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents` with the target folder id, I get the file creators and these names match the reviewers names. However, I also need a solution for a multi-step approval workflow. With my approach, I only get the name of the last reviewer, but no information about the in-between reviewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API for that.

Comment: Does Autodesk plans to publish such an API?